# Uploaded file have no content when uploaded from Remote IIS Server

Tags: c#, iis, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to upload files to Google Drive using ASP.NET Core 3.0, here is my code to upload the file.

```
GData.File fileMetadata = new GData.File()
{
    Id = null,
    Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
    MimeType = contentType
};

using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, contentType);
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Body = fileMetadata;

    request.ProgressChanged += (uploadProgress) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{uploadProgress.Status} {uploadProgress.BytesSent}");
    };

    request.ResponseReceived += (obj) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"File uploaded successfully  {obj.Id}");
    };

    request.Upload();
}
```

Problem i am facing is, this method work fine when i run it on local **IIS Server**. On Remote **IIS Server** this method run successfully but uploaded file do not have any content in it and show **0 size**

follow this link to test:
https://oauthdemo.coredata.ca/

Answer (score 0):

I tested the link you provided, but the test results show that the Content-Length has a size.
[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for having a look on it, have you check the uploaded file in your google drive?
it appears empty in Google Drive

Comment: I am using fiddler tool to get the uploaded content.

Comment: kindly check it in your google drive. I have been struggling to fix this issue since last 3 days. but haven't find any fix yet

Comment: here are the logs i have collected:

=> uploading: Verfication.png  image/png => C:\inetpub\GDriveAccess\Uploades\Verfication.png

=> uploading: image/png System.IO.FileStream

=> Upload Progress: Verfication.png Starting Bytes 0

=> File uploaded successfully: Verfication.png 

=> ID: 1tn5htZA6_-nZoCBYvne4Cbg6rn0ucwMw

=> Upload Progress: Verfication.png Completed  Bytes 0

Answer (score 0):

After struggling of whole day finally i have sort this issue.
It was due to the temp folder. i was using `FileStream` to create new file in temp folder. It was a A-Sync call due to which `FileStream` failed to create that file.